# why when you initialize array using initWithObjects the last item is "nil"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSArray creation with variable argument lists in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602458/nsarray-creation-with-variable-argument-lists-in-objective-c)

that's it actually the question is very simple. Xcode suggests that the last item is "nil" and I was wondering why.

```
array1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", nil];
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602458/nsarray-creation-with-variable-argument-lists-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

A null-termination (nil) character is used to determine the length of an array. Failure to properly terminate an array can result in buffer overflows and other undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from redirecting to the docs about [NSArray initWithObjects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithObjects%3a), it is worth noting that in general, with variadic functions (i.e. functions that take a variable number of arguments), either you specify the number of arguments upfront, or you terminate the argument list in some way. Nil is a good way of terminating the argument list and is the approach taken with `initWithObjects`.